# send data to serial Keil uvision

Tags: serialization, arm, keil, usart

I am looking for a GUI window in Keil uvision4 to send data **to** the serial. When I open serial window (USART #1-3), I am not able to type any characters on the screen to send to the serial.

Is there a way to manually type data that will be seen by the simulating environment (uvision) as having been received on the serial port?

Answer (score 0):

The [serial window](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/uv4/uv4_sm_uartcommunication.htm) should do what you're asking for in simulation. You may need to confirm that you have correctly configured your simulation, and the serial port you're using is the same one which you are monitoring in software.